# How to read not unique named ranges from the one of the sheet of workbook

Tags: java, apache-poi

How to read the named range from one of the sheet in **workbook**.Named range is present in **multiple sheet of workbook** with same name.

I tried with the workbook as a whole,not able to set the scope at sheet level

```
String cname = "TestName";
Workbook wb = getMyWorkbook(); // retrieve workbook

// retrieve the named range
int namedCellIdx = wb.getNameIndex(cellName);
Name aNamedCell = wb.getNameAt(namedCellIdx);

// retrieve the cell at the named range and test its contents
AreaReference aref = new AreaReference(aNamedCell.getRefersToFormula());
CellReference[] crefs = aref.getAllReferencedCells();
for (int i=0; i<crefs.length; i++) {
    Sheet s = wb.getSheet(crefs[i].getSheetName());
    Row r = sheet.getRow(crefs[i].getRow());
    Cell c = r.getCell(crefs[i].getCol());
    // extract the cell contents based on cell type etc.
}
```

Comment: Do using [Workbook.getNames(String name)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#getNames-java.lang.String-) to get all names having the given name. Then do using [Name.getSheetIndex](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Name.html#getSheetIndex--) to determine the sheet this name applies to.

Comment: Can we can't set the scope at Sheet level before reading the name range,otherwise there will be n number of iteration will happen for n number of sheet present in workbook?

Comment: No we can't. In `Excel` named ranges are stored at workbook level always. Maybe they have set a local sheet ID if they are not applied to the whole workbook. But the sheet's storage has not a place for storing named ranges.